# Problem with using uninitialized variables

Tags: c

I have two code snippets. Both give me a warning about using uninitialized variables, however, the former throws a segmentation fault while the latter DOESN'T. Please point out what has caused the difference here.

EDIT: They said it is undefined behaviour. So to be clear, i make a char **eligible_file which is undefined, then how can i get around with this without setting a fixed size for the variable?

the first:

```
glob_t glob1;
glob("*.log", GLOB_ERR, NULL, &glob1);
char** file_name = glob1.gl_pathv;
int file_num = glob1.gl_pathc;
char** eligible_file;
int j = 0;
if (compare_string(argv[1], "-o")) {
  for (int i = 0; i < file_num; i++) {
    int rc = file_or(file_name[i], argv, 2, argc);
    if (rc == 0) {
      eligible_file[j] = file_name[i]; // the fault occurs here
      j += 1;
    }
  }
} else {
  for (int i = 0; i < file_num; i++) {
    int rc = in_file(file_name[i], argv, 1, argc);
    if (rc == 0) {
      eligible_file[j] = "xasdax"; // the fault occurs here
      j += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

the latter:

```
char** fake;
char* me[] = {"qwedsa", "wqdxs", "qwdsx"};
if (1) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fake[i] = me[i];
  }
} else {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fake[i] = "wqxsaa";
  }
}
```

Comment: To me it's unclear what your question is. You already have the answer, i.e. uninitialized variables.

Comment: You got lucky! Had you observed the same behaviour, you'd assume everything was (kinda) ok and try to get rid of the warning. As you asked here, you get to know **both snippets are wrong**. Both have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @pmg If both have UB then why the second one work smoothly everytime i compile? That's strange.

Comment: "work smoothly' is an example of "anything",  and undefined behaviour means anything can happen

Comment: Undefined behavior is **undefined**.  "Appears to work just fine" is one possible result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both code snippets you write to a pointer without allocating memory for it.

**1st snippet**:

```
char** eligible_file;
...
eligible_file[j] = file_name[i]; // the fault occurs here
j += 1;
```

and

```
char** eligible_file;
...
eligible_file[j] = "xasdax"; // the fault occurs here
j += 1;
```

**2nd snippet:**

```
char** fake;
fake[i] = me[i];
...
fake[i] = "wqxsaa";
```

I am almost sure that in all cases, the error appears when the array index becomes greater than 0 - that is when writing in un-allocated memory occurs.

You should allocate memory in either of two ways:

1. Use proper arrays instead of pointers;
2. use malloc() or other similar function to allocate (enough) memory.

---

"undefined behavior" = whatever happens, good or bad, do not ask "why?"